# Are the terms Type and Class used interchangeably - Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have been studying scala quite a bit now. However, I have a simple question in regards to few terms used on many learning materials I find.

Are the term Type used interchangeably with Class?

Could a Type be replaced by a Class? and vice versa?

Ex. a Scala programmer would/could call the following case class a Type

```
type ProductId = String
type Quantity = Int

case class ShoppingCart(items: Map[ProductId, Quantity])
```

So, is `ShoppingCart` a Type, a class, or both, or depends on the paradigm ?

Also, does it have anything to do with Type Classes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short no, Scala offers a great variety of types, classes are one of the possible representations of type. A type refers to a natural language construct of defining a "template" of properties that can categorise a construct.

So we define a set of objects via a unifying set of characteristics, and we called the logical set of objects that "fit the template" a `type`, because all instances of that `type` share the properties.

So a `class` always has a `type`, but a `type` is not always a `class`.

Just for the sake of argument:

`trait T` is a type, it can have abstract methods, normal fully implemented methods, inherited methods, fields, type members, etc.

```
class A {
  type B
}
```

Both `A` and `B` have a type.

```
case class Bla
```

Also has a `type`.

`object C` also automatically generates the `C.type` definition, so `C` has type `C.type`.

```
def test(a: { def close: Unit() = println("closed")}
```

Is also a structural type, that can be exposed via a type lambda.

There are many more possible representations of a `type`. Just about the
only thing you wouldn't call a type is your first example, depending on how it's defined:

```
type A = String
```

We refer to that as a type alias, because it's not in essence a new type. It can be if you define `type A` as a type member with no particular implementation on a `trait` and then an implementor specifies a concrete `type`.

```
trait Holder {
  type Repr
}
```

And then override the type member like this:

```
trait StringHolder extends Holder {
  type Repr = String
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No there is difference between the two terms. A type doesn't have to belong to a certain class. For example,

```
  def fn[T <: Foo](t: T): Unit ={
  }
```

`fn` takes a type that extends `Foo`, the number of classes that can confirm to this type is potentially infinity.

Or even simpler,

```
val s = "hi"
```

Although `s` is instantiated as `String`, it still has 5 types: `Any`, `Serializable`,`String`, `Comparable[String]`, `CharSequence`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not quite.

Word `class` refers to very specific idea from object-oriented programming. Class defines some interface, that all of it's exemplars (instances) should fulfill (implement). So when we are talking about classes we usually mean things that were created using `class`, `trait` (`interface` in Java) - in Scala's case sometimes with combination to `abstract`, `case`, `final` or `sealed`. `objects` are also instances of a class, singleton class, but let's not get drown in details.

`Type` is a more generic term. It denotes some group of "things" that we named. Class is an example of a type, but so does primitives in languages that support them. In Scala you can also create a new type without creating new class.

As for the type class it is an idea that appeared in Haskell and was ported to other languages e.g. Scala. Basically it is a way to enforce ad-hoc polymorphism contracts: you need to have some functions overloaded for some type, you name that contract e.g. `Functor` and if you are saying that e.g. `List` have a Functor typeclass it means that there are functions overloaded for such contract. In Scala's case type classes are implemented as some trait implementation that is passed implicitly into your code basing on a type T which parametrizes the type class trait.